# Complex Analysis Modulus Property

Tags: complex-analysis

My teacher has asked an extra question apart from the one mentioned below in the picture:

[image]

What will happen if |z| = |w| = 1 ?

With respect to following answer:

[image]

I don't see any point in that question and feel that the answer will remain same, do I sound correct?